# ActivityInfo.loadIcon causes OutOfMemoryError if an app icon is a HD

Tags: android, performance

I came through this problem and looking for your input on the best approach on how to solve/avoid it & to bring other developers attention to it.

I'm using this code to fetch the installed apps data (label, icon, etc.). Everything was OK until I found my app using a lot of memory for no clear reason in my code.

```
    List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo ri : availableActivities){
        AppDetail appDetail = new AppDetail();

        appDetail.mAppIcon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager());
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I installed a new app which has a 3000*3000 dimension as an app icon (Really bad practice from the app developer), which increases the memory usage by 47MB. Which affected my app performance especially GridView scrolling.